# Why I can't use some Icons in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, icons

I formatted my pc, download the newest flutter SDK and surprised that last thing before I formatted my pc that there was a log_out and video_settings Icons, but after, it gives me error, and what made me confused that I found video_settings icon in [material icons page](https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=setting&icon=video_settings&style=outline) !!. so, any ideas why I can't use it in my app ?

Comment: run `flutter pub get`

Comment: I did, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgraded your version of flutter and there is an error, it means that those icons are no longer supported.

You will have to use another icon library. Take a look at font awesome, it provides a large range of icons ranging from barcodes to video. It's available for free on pubspec.

https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter